# Could sodium fluoride or aluminum accumulation in soils contribute to increased amounts of palmitic acid in food?

Tags: biochemistry

I am interested in the effects of plant environments on their biochemistry in relation to their effects on the environment and animals(us).

Could sodium fluoride or aluminum  accumulation in soils contribute to increased amounts of palmitic acid in food?

Thus increasing the inflammatory effects of certain foods?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24620580) explains the effects of fluoride ion concentrations to *Prosopis juliflora*.

> Both catalase (3.2 folds) and peroxidase (2.7 folds) enzymes activity increased with increase in F concentration.

Checking out Wikipedia articles about these enzymes, neither catalase not peroxidase are involved in the fatty acid biosynthesis. So as far as I know, I don't think there's any effect of fluorides in the biosynthesis of palmitic acid.

Also, regarding aluminum ions, [this](http://psjd.icm.edu.pl/psjd/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-abpv48i3p673kz) article explains aluminum toxicity as a hindrance to cell division and elongation, but nothing is mentioned about fatty acid synthesis.

**References:**

Saini, P, et al. “Effects of Fluoride on Germination, Early Growth and Antioxidant Enzyme Activities of Legume Plant Species Prosopis Juliflora.” Journal of Environmental Biology., U.S. National Library of Medicine, 34 Mar. 2013, www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24620580.

Mossor-Pietraszewska, T. (2017). Effect of aluminium on plant growth and metabolism.. [online] Psjd.icm.edu.pl. Available at: http://psjd.icm.edu.pl/psjd/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-abpv48i3p673kz [Accessed 23 Aug. 2017].

Comment: Good answer...for half of the question. But the OP asks about fluoride and aluminum, the latter of which is not mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @airhuff Fixed!

Comment: Laterite soils contain significant aluminum : You could look up if they have any effect on crops/forage.